# Detecting null value and replacing string C#

Tags: c#, csv

I'm currently having some issues with my CSV to SQL converter. The program is used to create commands to edit a databases user list updating or adding new ones. My issue is that if the user hasn't put a password in the CSV file i want it to be set as the user id. Ive currently got this IF statement trying to detect if the the string is empty but it always says that the string is empty and gives me my set pop up box even when i has text in the cell.

```
if (password != null)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Setting Password to User ID");
            }
```

Ive also tried password = password.replace(userid)but it doesnt change the string. Ive included my whole code below if that helps.

```
        private void LoadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Opens a browse box to allow the user to select which file, only CSV's allow allowed
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

        //empties text box when clicked | loads file location and name to load directory text box at top
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ConvertedText.Text = string.Empty;
            LoadDirectory.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
        }
        string filename = LoadDirectory.Text;
        string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
        string[] Fields;


        for (int i = 1; i < Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string outfile = "";
            Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
            string userid = Fields[0];
            string password = Fields[1];
            string fullname = Fields[2];
            string address = Fields[3];
            string telephone = Fields[4];
            string email = Fields[5];
            string role = Fields[6];
            string department = Fields[7];

            if (password != null)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Setting Password to User ID");
            }

            outfile += "IF exists (SELECT USERID FROM WUSERS WHERE USERID='" + userid + "')" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "begin" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += Environment.NewLine;

            outfile += "-- Update it" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "print 'updated'" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "update WUSERS set FULLNAME= '" + fullname + "' where userid= '" + userid + "'" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "update WUSERS set PW= '" + password + "' where userid= '" + userid + "'" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "update WUSERS set addr= '" + address + "' where userid= '" + userid + "'" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "update WUSERS set telno= '" + telephone + "' where userid= '" + userid + "'" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "update WUSERS set email= '" + email + "' where userid= '" + userid + "'" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "update WUSERS set ROLEID= '" + role + "' where userid= '" + userid + "'" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "update WUSERS set dept= '" + department + "' where userid= '" + userid + "'" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "end" + Environment.NewLine;

            outfile += "else" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "begin" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "-- add it" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "print 'added'" + Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "insert into WUSERS (USERID,PW,FULLNAME,ADDR,TELNO,EMAIL,ROLEID,DEPT) Values ('" + userid + "','" + password + "','" + fullname + "','" + address + "','" + telephone + "','" + email + "','" + role + "','" + department + "')";
            outfile += Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "end";
            outfile += Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
            outfile += Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += Environment.NewLine;
            outfile += Environment.NewLine;

            ConvertedText.AppendText(outfile);

        }

    }
```

Thank you in advance for any input.

Owen

Comment: `password = password ?? userid;`?

Comment: It may just be a personal preference thing, but personally I would try and reduce the `outfile += "..." + full name + "...." + Environment.NewLine` lines to something like `outfile += $"... {fullname} where userid = {id} \n`, with `\n` replacing `Environment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you want

```
if (password == null)
```

but I suggest you to use the more complete

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
   ...error message...
```

Said that I can't avoid to warn you about the code that follow. I hope that all those UPDATE WUSERS are not used to really update a database. This method of string concatenation is well know for its problems, from the more simple to the worst one you get, Syntax Errors, Parsing errors, Sql Injection attacks.

Comment: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` is the best way to check a string. +1

Comment: Unless the user's password really is `"        "` :-P

Comment: @David awh, well it is a complicated world. We can go back to a IsNullOrEmpty then?

Answer (score 0):

**Consider Existing Methods**

Rather than comparing to null directly, you may want to use a more appropriate method like [`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`String.IsNullorWhiteSpace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) methods based on your preferences / requirements:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Setting Password to User ID");
}
```

**Use Parameterization instead of String Concatenation**

Your existing code currently leaves you susceptible to SQL Injection attacks as you are just concatenating values to build your query as seen below :

```
"... SELECT WHERE USERID='" + userid + "')" + Environment.NewLine;
```

What you should consider doing instead would be to use parameters within your query and then later set the values of those parameters prior to executing :

```
"... SELECT WHERE USERID= @userid)" + Environment.NewLine;
```

This can not only better protect you from SQL Injection nastiness, but it can also make your queries much easier to read and reduce the likelihood of typographical-related syntax errors from popping up (i.e. missing quotes around values, etc.).